# How can i put the hyperlink in a contact form in wordpress next to the checkbox message?

Tags: wordpress

I have added a required checkbox field to contact form 7 in wordpress. I added and the hyperlink to send the user in Terms and Conditions page.
This is the checkbox field I added:
[checkbox* term_and_conditions "I have read and accepted the"][Terms and Conditions](https://example)
But when i run the contact form, the hyperlink: "Terms and Conditions", appears in the next line from the message: "I have read and accepted the" and the message it appears just like that:
I have read and accepted the
Terms and Conditions.

My question is, how can i make the "Terms and Conditions" appears in the same line with "I have read and accepted the"?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to write it this way:

```
[checkbox* term_and_conditions] I have read and accepted the <a href="https://example">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

...and add CSS to place the text on the same line as the checkbox, for example by adding `display: flex` to the `label` tag. This is best done by adding a CSS class to the checkbox element in the form definition and using that class as a selector (possibly also containing the parent elements) for a CSS rule that contains `display: flex`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i solve it with a different way. Inserted this code [acceptance term]I have read and accepted the <a href="https://example">Terms and Conditions</a> [/acceptance] and then inserted the following code: "acceptance_as_validation: on" in the Additional Settings tab. 
So thank you for your fast answer!